# iText issues with adding Header and Footer to an dexisting pdf

Tags: java, itext, footer

I have an existing pdf and I need to add a Header (image) and Footer (page number) to it. I have tried PDFStamper and HeaderFooter classes. The Header and Footer are displaying with PDFStamper but, the existing text is overlapping on the header and footer.

How do I squeeze the existing content between the header and footer?

Comment: It's remotely possible that someone could make an educated guess, but it would still be hugely helpful to add a small code sample.

Comment: +1 Hannele; in addition to the code, though, you seem to want to not be happy with the current format of your PDF; after all, you want to squeeze it to make place for header and footer. Thus, please also supply a sample PDF and explain what exactly you want to get.